# Using just the ruler draw the orthogonal of $(AB)$ in a given point $P$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Idon't know how to solve this problems :

Let $[AB]$ be a diameter of a given circle (it's center is unknown)

- Using just the ruler drow the orthogonal of $(AB)$ in a given point $P$ (arbitrary , outside or  inside )
  [image]

  Can you explain , assist ?

I'm thankful

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw $AP$ and $BP$ and get their intersection with the circle $D$ and $E$.
Then $AE$ and $BD$ meets at the point $C$ belonging to the required perpendicular.

---

*Proof.* $BE\perp AC$ and $AD\perp BC$, hence $P$ is the orthocenter of the triangle $ABC$.

[image]

Comment: very nice solution , super down ! Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than providing complete solution. Also, ask OP for their attempt or what more they know about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).